# When will iAd for iPad be available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, app-store, iad

anyone know when iAds for iPad will be available? it seems to only be available for iPhone at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People in the iOS Developer Programme are signed up to an NDA that prevents them commenting on any software they have access to, including future releases of the OS or developer tools.

However, lots of sites like [this one](http://www.macstories.net/ipad/apple-opens-ios-4-2-app-submissions-iad-coming-to-ipad/) are reporting that iAds will be present in iOS 4.2, which Apple [have announced](http://www.apple.com/ipad/software-update/) will arrive during November (ie, within the next two and a half weeks at this point).